# My For loop isn't putting the values brought in every loop into my array

Tags: c

My array is created with an initial size of 1 so when he first iteration of the for loop runs the first piece of data brought across from the telemetry array gets put into the first position in the array or position 0 which is assigned by the counter variable which is initially set at 0, this is increases every iteration of the for loop, I then re allocate the memory of my array by one by using the counter variable plus one as the counter variable would be one less than I need every iteration of the loop, this then means the size of the array is 2 and then the second piece of data gets put into position 1 of the array as this is how large the counter is at the start of the second iteration of the for loop. My issue is that the data isn't being put into my array for whatever reason, the data is being brought from the telemetry array fine as I have set a temporary function to print what is coming from the telemetry array and what is being put into my array. I need to re allocate memory every loop as I don't know how large my array needs to be. I also have a sorting function and a for loop to print out all the data at the end of the code which work fine, it's just not working due to the values not being put in my array.

This is my code:

```
void filterBySensorTypeAvg(TelemetryData* telemetryArray, int arraySize) {
    char sensorType[20];
    int counter = 0;
    float sum = 0, avg = 0;
    float* sensorArray = malloc(1 * sizeof(float));
    
    printf("Enter the sensor type to filter: ");

#if (_MSC_VER > 1600)
    scanf_s("%19s", sensorType,
        (unsigned)(sizeof(sensorType) / sizeof(sensorType[0])));
#else
    scanf("%19s", sensorType);
#endif

    printf("Telemetry Data for Sensor Type '%s':\n", sensorType);
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(telemetryArray[i].sensorType, sensorType) == 0) {
            sum += telemetryArray[i].measurement;
            sensorArray[counter] = telemetryArray[i].measurement;
            counter++;
            sensorArray = (int*)realloc(sensorArray, (counter + 1) * sizeof(int));
            printf("%.2f %d\n", telemetryArray[i].measurement, sensorArray[i]);
            if (counter > 20) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    avg = sum / counter;
    printf("The Average %s is %.2f from a total of %.2f\n", sensorType, avg, sum);

    qsort(sensorArray, counter, sizeof(int), compare);
    
//    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
//        printf("%.2f, ", sensorArray[i]);
//    }

    printf("\n\n\nArraySize: %i\n\n", arraySize);
}
```

This is my output:

[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL6fE.png)

Comment: You are printing a `float` variable using a `%d` format.

Comment: @Nathan Initially you allocated an array of floats float* sensorArray = malloc(1 * sizeof(float)); Then you are reallocating it as an array of integers  sensorArray = (int*)realloc(sensorArray, (counter + 1) * sizeof(int));.You need to decide which type of the array you want.:)

Comment: Aside: if you put `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` before the `#include` statements you can forget all about Microsoft's false assertion that `scanf` is deprecated.

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings. They show the mismatch of types. Also see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and `realloc()`.

Comment: realloc `sizeof(int)` should be `float`. Same in qsort. You seem confused over which types your variables were declared as.

Comment: `sizeof(sensorType) / sizeof(sensorType[0]` This is guaranteed to be equal to `sizeof(sensorType)`.